# Multiple distinct Content-Disposition headers received from server in Jasperreports

Tags: java, servlets, http-headers, jasper-reports

I'm trying to set content-disposition header in response of servlet, but i get this error in browser. What should i do?

> **Duplicate headers received from server**
>
> The response from the server
> contained duplicate headers. This problem is generally the result of a
> misconfigured website or proxy. Only the website or proxy
> administrator can fix this issue.
>
> Error 349 (net::ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_MULTIPLE_CONTENT_DISPOSITION): Multiple
> distinct Content-Disposition headers received. This is disallowed to
> protect against HTTP response splitting attacks.

Here my servlet controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/**/paymentOrderReport.pdf")
public class PaymentOrderReportViewController extends org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController {
    
    private PaymentDao paymentDao;
    private JasperPdfView pdfView;

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "report.pdf");

        PaymentOrderEntity paymentOrderEntity = null;
        String traceCode = request.getParameter(ParamConstants.TRACE_CODE);

        if (traceCode != null) {
            PaymentSheetRequestEntity payRequestEntity = paymentDao.loadByUniqueProperty(PaymentSheetRequestEntity.PROP_TRACE_CODE,
                    traceCode);
            if (payRequestEntity != null) {
                paymentOrderEntity = payRequestEntity.getPaymentOrder();
            }
        }

        if (paymentOrderEntity != null) {
            List<PaymentOrderEntity> result = new ArrayList<PaymentOrderEntity>();
            result.add(paymentOrderEntity);
            JRDataSource jrDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(result);

            Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            model.put("reportData", jrDataSource);

            return new ModelAndView(pdfView, model);
        }
        return null;
    }
    
    public void setPaymentDao(PaymentDao paymentDao) {
        this.paymentDao = paymentDao;
    }

    public void setPdfView(JasperPdfView pdfView) {
        this.pdfView = pdfView;
    }
}
```

And JasperPdfView Class:

```
public class JasperPdfView extends AbstractJasperReportsView {
    
    @Override
    protected void renderReport(JasperPrint populatedReport, Map<String, Object> model, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        JRPdfExporter jrPdfExporter = new JRPdfExporter();
        if (getConvertedExporterParameters() != null) {
            jrPdfExporter.setParameters(getConvertedExporterParameters());
        }
        jrPdfExporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, populatedReport);
        jrPdfExporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, response.getOutputStream());
        jrPdfExporter.exportReport();
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Any progress in that? I'm getting the same error

Comment: Any progress? I am facing a similar issue in Chrome browser (no issues in all other browsers - IE, FF, Safari)

Answer (score 36):

Google Chrome might display this error message if you are downloading a file which has a comma in the file name. Were you really using just "report.pdf" as filename?

Having read the [HTTP specs](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2) the Content-Disposition header (which is not part of the HTTP spec itself) should not include a comma character, because it will be treated as a separator for two different headers.

> Multiple message-header fields with the same field-name MAY be present in a message if and only if the entire field-value for that header field is defined as a comma-separated list [i.e., #(values)]. It MUST be possible to combine the multiple header fields into one "field-name: field-value" pair, without changing the semantics of the message, by appending each subsequent field-value to the first, each separated by a comma.

So if your filename were report,May2014.pdf then Chrome interprets

`Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=report,May2014.pdf`

as two values for the same http message header

`Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=report`

`Content-Disposition: May2014.pdf`

which in turn is interpreted as a [HTTP response splitting attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_response_splitting), probably because there shall actually be no multiple Content-Disposition header values in a single HTTP response.

Other browsers does not seem to mind the comma in the file name.

Answer (score 4):

Incorrect:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename="+filename+);
```

Correct:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=\""+filename+"\"");
```