# Android with HttpURLConnection using POST method gives EOFException

Tags: java, android, http, file-upload, httpurlconnection

I am getting this weird scenario whenever i make request using POST with request body for upload file, my header part won't contain anything except contentType, whenever i try to read response it gives me EOFException, below is my code any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    public static Response executeFWUploadRequest(Context context, String fileName, String version,
                                              String checksum, File payload, int retry) {


    if (CommonUtils.isConnectedToWiFi(context)) {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        String boundary = "+++++";
        String LINE_FEED = "\n";
        try {
            URL url = new URL(CommonUtils.UPLOAD_URL);

            CommonUtils.writeLog("HTTP Client REQUEST URL = " + url);

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            urlConnection.setRequestMethod(METHOD_POST);
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty(Tag.CONTENT_TYPE_TAG, "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(TimeOut);
            urlConnection.setReadTimeout(TimeOut);

            OutputStream outputStream = urlConnection.getOutputStream();

            BufferedOutputStream dos = new BufferedOutputStream(outputStream);
            dos.flush();
            String partition = "--" + boundary;
            dos.write(LINE_FEED.getBytes());

            dos.write(partition.getBytes());
            dos.write(LINE_FEED.getBytes());
            String disp3 = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + Tag.FILE_LENGTH_FIELD + "\"" + LINE_FEED + LINE_FEED + "value = \"" + payload.length() + "\"";
            dos.write(disp3.getBytes());
            dos.write(LINE_FEED.getBytes());

            dos.write(partition.getBytes());
            dos.write(LINE_FEED.getBytes());
            String dis1 = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + Tag.VERSION_TAG + "\"" + LINE_FEED + LINE_FEED + "value = \"" + version + "\"";
            dos.write(dis1.getBytes());
            dos.write(LINE_FEED.getBytes());

            dos.write(partition.getBytes());
            dos.write(LINE_FEED.getBytes());
            String disp2 = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + Tag.CHECKSUM_TAG + "\"" + LINE_FEED + LINE_FEED + "value = \"" + checksum + "\"";
            dos.write(disp2.getBytes());
            dos.write(LINE_FEED.getBytes());

            dos.write(partition.getBytes());
            dos.write(LINE_FEED.getBytes());
            String disp4 = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file \"; " + Tag.FILE_NAME_TAG + "=\"" + payload.getName() + "\"";
            dos.write(disp4.getBytes());
            dos.write(LINE_FEED.getBytes());
            String disp5 = Tag.CONTENT_TYPE_TAG + ": " + Tag.STREAM_CONTENT_TYPE_VALUE;
            dos.write(disp5.getBytes());
            dos.write(LINE_FEED.getBytes());
            dos.write(LINE_FEED.getBytes());

            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(payload);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int bytesRead = -1;
            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                dos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }

            dos.write(LINE_FEED.getBytes());
            dos.write((partition + "--").getBytes());
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();
            //tried with and with out below 2 lines
            outputStream.close();
            urlConnection.connect();
            //This line gives error its method to read response with its patch
            return readData(urlConnection,0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
        }
    } else {
        CommonUtils.writeLog("HTTP Client : Wifi connection is not available");
    }
    return null;
}




private static final int MAX_RETRY = 5;
private static Response readData(HttpURLConnection urlConnection, int retry) {
    Response objResponse = null;
    try {
        objResponse = new Response();
        String content;
        if (retry < MAX_RETRY) {
            objResponse.setResponseCode(urlConnection.getResponseCode());

            if (objResponse.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                content = convertInputStreamToString(new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection
                        .getInputStream()));
                objResponse.setResponseContent(content);
            } else {
                content = convertInputStreamToString(new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection
                        .getErrorStream()));
                objResponse.setResponseContent(content);
            }
        }
    } catch (EOFException eof) {
        eof.printStackTrace();
        readData(urlConnection, retry + 1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return objResponse;
}
```

Here return type of Response is custom POJO class which store response code and response content.

Comment: Looks rather strange to have multiple `String disp* = "Content-Disposition: form-data; ` headers

Comment: well it just a variable name used for body part as BOS only allow to write byte which is being written by disp*.getBytes() and from my r&d related problem i can say multiple content-disposition allowed in request body.

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is having multiple `Content-Disposition` headers in the HTTP Request. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13578428/duplicate-headers-received-from-server

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15599618/multiple-distinct-content-disposition-headers-received-from-server-in-jasperrepo

Comment: thanks scary let me give a try with header that what i understand from link with single "Content-Disposition"

Comment: hi scary without luck still getting EOFException now i added every dis* into header separately and body only contain file data..

Comment: we can set multiple Content-Disposition so its definitely not an issues.